# Use different connection when running Azure Logic App workflow locally

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I'm triggering a workflow from a storage queue. Inside Azure the connection uses a ManagedServiceIdentity. This option is not locally available however. Locally I can use a connection string with value "UseDevelopmentStorage=true".

However, the structure of the connection inside the connections.json is different between the managed identity and connection string types. So changing a simple app setting in the local.settings.json doesn't work.

Connection example with managed identity:

```json
"app-storage-queue-connection": {
  "parameterValues": {
    "connectionString": "@appsetting('app-storage-queue-endpoint')"
  },
  "parameterSetName": "connectionString",
  ...
}
```

Connection example with connection string:

```json
"app-storage-queue-connection": {
    "parameterValues": {
        "authProvider": {
            "Type": "ManagedServiceIdentity"
        },
        "queueServiceUri": "@appsetting('app-storage-queue-endpoint')"
    },
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to create a 'local.connections.json' file similar to the 'local.settings.json' file? Or to solve this issue another way?

I tried creating a local.connections.json, but it doesn't work.

A workaround would be to configure the connections.json with the local 'connection string' connection. Create a 'remote.connections.json' with the managed identity connection and use that during deployment from my Azure Pipeline. But I'm hoping there is a more elegant way.

Comment: I am looking to do the exact same thing so curious about any solutions. One option I am considering is to implement a task that renames files as part of my Azure Devops pipeline. That should allow me to create environment-specific JSON files, only one of which would be renamed to `connection.json` at build and deployment time.